# Apache2: module evasive20_module is already loaded, skipping

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apache-2.2

I am installing mod_evasive on my Ubuntu LAMP server. I followed the simple directions:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-evasive
sudo mkdir /var/log/mod_evasive
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/mod_evasive/
sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-evasive.conf

<ifmodule mod_evasive20.c>
   DOSHashTableSize 3097
   DOSPageCount  2
   DOSSiteCount  50
   DOSPageInterval 1
   DOSSiteInterval  1
   DOSBlockingPeriod  10
   DOSLogDir   /var/log/mod_evasive
   DOSEmailNotify  EMAIL@DOMAIN.com
</ifmodule>

sudo a2enmod mod-evasive
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But whenever I restart Apache, I receive the following warning:

```
[Mon Jan 28 20:27:16 2013] [warn] module evasive20_module is already loaded, skipping
 ... waiting [Mon Jan 28 20:27:18 2013] [warn] module evasive20_module is already loaded, skipping
```

I tried running `perl /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-evasive/examples/test.pl` to test it out, however I keep receiving `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`, never a `403 Forbidden`. Does anyone know what might be going on? As you saw above, the configration is located at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-evasive.conf` and the load file (`/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-evasive.load`) contains:

```
LoadModule evasive20_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_evasive20.so
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module is trying to load twice, so you should comment out one of the following lines:

If you're using Apache 1.3, in `/etc/httpd/mods-enabled/evasive20.load` comment out

```
LoadModule evasive_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_evasive.so
```

If you're using Apache 2, in `/etc/httpd/mods-enabled/mod-evasive.load` comment out

```
LoadModule evasive20_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_evasive20.so
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. This site, like the other Stack Exchange trilogy sites Stack Overflow and Super User, [uses English as its official language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/142424). I have translated your answer for you, however in the future please post questions, answers, and comments on this site in English. Thanks!